# "Authorization has been denied for this request" in production environment only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using WebAPI and Owin with the following authentication setup. Locally, I can register, get a token, and make API requests that have the [Authorize] annotation on them. In production, I can register **and get a token**, but I get the error in the title when I try to hit an endpoint with the [Authorize] annotation.

Given that it works locally, I'm skeptical that it's a code problem. And I build and deploy all .dlls to the production server, so the references should all be the same version. Could it be a difference in IIS configuration? Comparing the two, I don't see anything jumping out at me, but I could be missing something.

And in case it matters, I use Web Deploy from Visual Studio to push the site to production. I also use the exact same web.config for both environments, except that I transform the connection string for production.

**Startup.cs**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.API.Startup))]
namespace MyProject.API
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

**App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.API
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Allow access_token to be passed as a query parameter
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.QueryString.HasValue)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization")))
                    {
                        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.Request.QueryString.Value);
                        string token = queryString.Get("access_token");

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                        {
                            context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new[] { string.Format("Bearer {0}", token) });
                        }
                    }
                }

                await next.Invoke();
            });

            app.CreatePerOwinContext(MyProjectDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    DependencyInjectorConfig.RegisterDependencies();
    MappingConfig.RegisterMappings(); // Autofac stuff
    Database.SetInitializer(new MyProjectInitializer());
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the authorization header in your http requests if it contains any value after successfully logging-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! The login call was using the LOCAL api, while the rest of the routes were using the production api. Fixing that solved my problem.